# How to know if the application is visible in the user interface or not

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on a WPF application where I need to know if my application is visible to the user or not. I tried Application.Current.Activated/Deactivated events to change a bool property and use this bool to check as per my requirements. Everything works fine except that the Deactivated event is getting called when a popup (like gtalk chat window) opens or I click in the taskbar, so my bool is changing.

What can I do to check if my app is visible to the user rather than activated/deactivated (which checks if my application is the foreground app or not)?

```
    Application.Current.Activated += Current_Activated;

    Application.Current.Deactivated += Current_Deactivated;

    void Current_Deactivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsActive = false;
    }

    void Current_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsActive = true;
    }
```

And if !IsActive I am showing the notification.

Comment: Posting code never hurts as it shows your starting point

Comment: Why do you need to know if your window is partially visible to a user, even when is not active? What you are trying to achieve? You window is either `Active`  (has keyboard/mouse input) or not. When you switch to other application (even a small popup window, covering 0.1% of your window) or taskbar, you window is *inactive*. You window is `Visible` or completely invisible (hidden/minimized), however, if you move window far away to become *invisible for you* (you can't see a single pixel of window), it is still `Visible`, because Windows doesn't care about *what you see*.

Comment: @Sinatr My app is similar to Skype (messenger app). When my app is not in the foreground I need to show a notifications if a message arrives. The problem is when the app is not the foreground one but still visible to the user I don't need to show the notification.

Comment: Define *foreground*? Skype window can be *hidden* (closed) or *minimized*. When minimized, it is visible in taskbar and you can click there or use alt-tab to make it active. When hidden, it is not in taskbar (alt-tab not showing it) and you have to use tray icon (dblclick or right-click menu) to restore it. When do you want to show notifications and when do not?

Answer (score 1):

```
protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
    HwndSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
    source.AddHook(WndProc);
}

private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    if (msg == 0x1c)
    {
        OnActivateApp(wParam != IntPtr.Zero);
    }
    return IntPtr.Zero;
}

protected void OnActivateApp(bool activate)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Activate {0}", activate);
}
```

Excuse me, do not write and do not understand English very well, but this article has enhanced the solution http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/704390/How-to-be-Notified-when-your-application-is-active

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Application.Windows` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.windows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to tell you which `Window`s have been instantiated and not closed (currently open) and then use the [`Window.IsActive` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.isactive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to tell if any of them are currently active:

```
Window activeWindow = 
    Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().SingleOrDefault(w => w.IsActive)); 
if (activeWindow != null) 
{
    // activeWindow is the active Window
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There's a `VisibilityChanged` Event where you can hook up. You'll find the current visibility state in its `EventArgs`.

Let me know if I need to post any code ;-)

Comment: There is nothing to do with `VisibilityChanged` when we need to check whether window is partially visible.

Comment: @AnatoliiGabuza Can you tell us how to do that!